# How to make one UIView stay in fixed position, while all the rest autorotates?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, autorotate

I'm trying to make a UI with a UINavigationController that presents some UIViewController with a child UIViewController as a sidebar view. In Landscape orientation it shall be a stripe on the right side. Upon rotation it to portrait it shall stay on that physical side, while the UINavigationController autorotates and everything else with it. In portrait orientation the sidebar has therefore become a bottombar.

Have a look at the mockup, please.  [UI Mockup](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1041539/ui.pdf)

Now, how to do this? Returning `NO` for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation:` doesn't stop the rotation of that sidebar :-/

Answer (score 2):

Change the frame and/or the transform of the view in the view controller's autorotation detecting method, something like this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)to duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    // Calculate the new frame and rotation angle of the view
    // e. g.:

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(to)) {
        theView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 924, 768, 100);
        theView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } else {
        theView.frame = CGRectMake(924, 0, 100, 768);
        theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: No, that's not it. While it approximates the desired end situation, it animates the bar all over the screen to get there. Instead, I'd like the view to just not move anywhere (respectively make it look as if it didn't move, since it definitely has to counter the automatic transformations that the controller does to it)

Comment: @leberwurstsaft then make it an image. It's the only reasonable solution.

Comment: How would that be any different from animation a UIView? This view is not static, it contains subviews itself. And strictly speaking, it shouldn't just stay in place, but extend its length to the full width of the containing view in portrait and back to the height of the containing view in landscape. So there is a bit of size change. But the position has to be fixed in relation to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGAffineTransform t;
//You have to caculate the angel of view controller rotating    
CGFloat rotateAngel = M_PI / 2;//replace 'M_PI / 2' with your view controllers rotation angel
t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotateAngel);
[view setTransform:t];
```

Comment: These kinds of solution don't work. I tried a lot of transformation code to make it appear to stay in place.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to separate the side view from the navigation controller view (don't make it child view). So you have more control about the rotation. You might rotate the images inside the view anyway.

Comment: I had tried that also, the setup being: An outer controller that has the navigation controller as a child and the subview that shouldn't rotate. I set the outer controller to not auto-rotate and the presented controllers in the navigation controller to auto-rotate, but then everything stopped auto-rotating. Once the outer (parent) controller is set to auto-rotate, it will rotate them all. So, no, that doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay. What about this. Make that everything is autorotating as expected. In willRotateToInterfaceOrientation you hide the view you want to stick at one side. In didRotateToInterfaceOrientation the interface is completely rotated. Here you place your view where you want it to be and show it again.

Comment: Right, thats exactly what I settled for, since I couldn't get it to work. But its not nice, and I don't like that there seems to be no real solution to it. I hoped, I had missed something. Now I need to manually reposition, resize, animate the view in order not to look like ass while rotating.    But thank you anyway!

Comment: Never mind. I did something similar and as you have to rotate the images inside anyway I find it from the users point of view not disturbing if a view slides out/in. Good luck.

Comment: One more thing. Have you tried overwriting layoutSubview? You could store frame and transform call super and afterwards restore everything.

Comment: No, I haven't, but I might give it a shot in a spare minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use auto rotation to do this as you have mixed two view controllers on one screen. Turn off auto rotation on both parent and child  view controllers, and do the desired transformations yourself when you detect rotation. Auto rotate will rotate all views under the controller view (including the subview controlled by your other view controller).

Alternatively you could slide the view off first (when you receive willRotateToInterfaceOrientation), and then slide it back on in the correct orientation when you receive didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: Yes, the sliding/fading solution is what I do now, since it just wouldn't work. Doing this myself is not worth the trouble for the task at hand, though. I just thought it would make for a nice behaviour in this case, but no luck.

Comment: It's really not very much trouble to do by hand, as you can rotate the main view by changing its transform, then just change the frame of the subview to fit the bottom of the screen or the side of the screen, that's just two operations. You might find that's easier than the sliding/fading solution and trying to use auto-rotate as you will completely control the animation.

Comment: There's so much more inside the rotating main view that relies on the auto-rotation, I don't think it'd boild down to just these two operations.